# Size an image to a percentage of html window

Tags: html, css, image

Is it possible to define an image by a percentage of the document window? It's nested in several div tags, so it would be to somehow define its height% in reference to the window, rather than its parent tag. In effect, something like this...

```
<img src="image.jpg"  height="50% of window"/>
```

Comment: percentages are always relative to the parent element, this could be done with JavaScript

Answer (score 24):

You can use the viewport's height and width.

For example, the following class will make the element half the size of the viewport.

```
.size {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/52jXj/)

This is a **pure CSS3** solution, but it has some [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw) issues.

Answer (score 5):

Not with CSS, but you could with JavaScript:

```
yourImage.height = Math.floor(window.innerHeight / 2)
```

Comment: ok great! I'm a little slow with JavaScript. Do I need to declare a variable? ie this is what I wrote at the beginning of my javascript page that loads with the file (which is named white.jpg)
   white.height = Math.floor(window.innerHeight / 2);

Comment: @user962642 You can add an `id` to your image, and say `document.getElementById('yourImagesId').height = ...`

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution for this [here](http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio).  The example given in that article did not work for me when I added an image to the mix.  However, I enhanced it creating a "card" layout that works with an image and text.

```
.course-card-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    background-color:silver;
}
.course-card-aspect-ratio {
    padding-top: 150%;
}
.course-card-image {
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}
.course-card {
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:10px;  
  bottom:10px;
  right:10px;
  background-color:white;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
}
```

Adjust course-card-aspect-ratio value to the multiple you desire.

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hthL4g6/1/).

Answer (score -1):

Or with jQuery:

$("#yourimageselector").height($(window).height());

Comment: Or for 50%...divide that window height by 2.

Comment: How do I divide that window height by 2?

Comment: $("#yourimageselector").height($(window).height() / 2);